# Sort list of words based on the frequency of the word in another list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of words that I want to reorder based on the frequency of its occurrence as a substring in another list of strings:

```
list_to_reorder=['apm', 'mba', 'bac', 'ms', 'grad']
list_with_strings=['don.mba', 'kun.ms', 'bob.mba', 'liz.grad', 'lily.apm', 'tina.mba', 'sash.ms', 'gin.grad', 'moma.bs']
```

So if I look at the count of occurrences of each element in list_to_reorder, I get:

```
mba => 3
ms  => 2
grad=> 2
apm => 1
bs  => 1
```

and then would like to reorder the first list like this which is the expected result:

```
['mba', 'ms', 'grad', 'apm', 'bac']
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you tagged `pandas`? Didn't see any pandas object referenced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
from collections import Counter

>>> d = Counter([x.split('.')[-1] for x in list_with_strings])
>>> sorted(list_to_reorder, key= lambda x: d[x], reverse=True)
['mba', 'ms', 'grad', 'apm', 'bac']
```

Can also use [`d.__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) as the `key`, but I'd say it gets less intuitive